# How to populate a field inside a embedded document in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a model "Post" that is something like this

```
{
   // Some other fields
   comments: [
    new mongoose.Schema({
      content: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Content for a comment is required."],
      },
      author: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: [true, "Author for a comment is required."],
      },
    }),
}
```

I cannot figure out a way to populate the `author` field inside `comment` after fetching posts. How may I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Populating across multiple levels](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate)

```
Post.find({ }).populate({
    path: 'comments',
    populate: { path: 'author' }
});
```

Comment: Ahhhhh.. I had earlier came across similar  solution. But I thought for this to work 'comments' also had to be reference to another document. It worked. Thank you.